# How to install specific version of Virtualbox with homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew, virtualbox, versioning

I have an issue with last version of virtualbox on MacOS M1, and apparently, I can use an older version to fix it

I tried :

```
brew cask install virtualbox@6.1.26

brew cask reinstall virtualbox@6.1.26

brew reinstall virtualbox@6.1.26   

brew install --cask virtualbox@6.1.26

brew install virtualhost.sh@6.1.26
```

I also tried to install latest virtualbox with

```
brew reinstall virtualbox
```

and switch the version with :

```
brew switch virtualbox 6.1.26
```

But nothing works, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow a three stepped guideline :

1. Cask file
2. Modify the Cask file
3. Reinstall your package

This link is helping you during the process :

[Homebrew Cask to install specific version of package](https://zeckli.github.io/en/2016/11/05/use-homebrew-cask-to-downgrad-or-install-en.html)

Comment: That blog post is missing information, as far as I can tell. It says, "all we have to do is to change the values of the version and the sha256," but doesn't mention how to get the sha256 for a given version. That would seem to be an important detail to omit.
Finally, SO answers should stand on their own better. (Links inevitably die.)

Additionally, `brew cask` is no longer a command in 2022, so those references should be replaced with, eg., `brew subcommand --cask`.